# Error in adding enemies to list with FindGameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help with that. I want to add to list all enemies in map with `drap` tag. Can you have any solutions?

```cs
List<GameObject> _enemies = new List<GameObject>();

_enemies.Add(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("drap"));
```

And error here:

> (26,22): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.GameObject[]' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

Comment: This is saying that FindGameObjectsWithTag is an array, and Add cannot take an array. You probably want [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

You should write it like this:

```
List<GameObject> _enemies = new List<GameObject>();

_enemies.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("drap"));
```

'FindGameObjectsWithTag()' returns an Array which is why you need to use AddRange(). This should work if you copy it, based on what you posted and what the documentation provides.

Comment: error CS1061: 'GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no accessible extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Kajzera you don't need to write the .ToList() because AddRange() is able to append an Array(atleast thats what the documentation says). I forgot to delete it when editing to AddRange(), my appologies